# A basis for forms of degree $d$ (Fulton, 2.35)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I am trying to solve this exercise from Fulton's book:

> (2.35)(c) Let $L_1, L_2, \dots,$ and $M_1, M_2, \dots$ be sequences of nonzero linear forms in $k[X,Y]$ and assume no $L_i = \lambda M_j$ for $\lambda \in k$. Let $A_{ij} = L_1L_2 \cdots L_i M_1 M_2 \cdots M_j$, $i,j \ge 0$ and $A_{00} = 1$. Show that $\{A_{ij} : i+j = d\}$ is a basis for $V(d,2)$ (the forms of degree $d$ in $k[X,Y]$).

My initial strategy was to use induction on $d$. I was able to show it is true for $d = 1$ by showing $cX+dY$ has a unique representation as $aL_1 + bM_1$ if and only if a determinant is nonzero, which translated to $L_1 \neq \lambda M_1$ for $\lambda \in k$. But now the inductive step is giving me trouble. I'm not sure how to reduce to the previous case because dehomogeonizing gives something that is no longer a form.

Answer (score 2):

I do not see how you could use induction on this problem, but a more direct approach works here.

Since the monomials $X^iY^{d-i}$ for $0\leq i \leq d$ form a basis of $V(d,2)$, we have that $\dim V(d,2)=d+1$ (this is the previous part of exercise 2.35 in Fulton's book "Algebraic Curves"). Also, there are exactly $d+1$ polynomials $A_{ij}$, so we only need to check that they are linearly independent.

Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that there is a non-trivial linear combination 
$$\sum_{i,j}\lambda_{ij}\,A_{ij}=0\,.$$
At least there must be a couple of pairs $(i,j)$ such that $\lambda_{ij}\neq0$. 
Then, let $r$ be the greatest index $i$ such that $\lambda_{ij}\neq 0$ and let $s=d-i$ (this is the corresponding $j$). We can assume, up to changing the roles of $i$ and $j$, that $r>0$. By our choice of $r$, we obtain an expression of the form 
$$A_{rs}=\sum_{i,j}\mu_{ij}\,A_{ij}$$
where the indices in the sum of the RHS satisfy that $i<r$ and $j>s$. That is, 
$$L_1\ldots L_rM_1\ldots M_s=\sum_{i,j}\mu_{ij}\,L_1\ldots L_iM_1\ldots M_s\ldots M_j$$ 
and, dividing by $M_1\ldots M_s$, we obtain that 
$$L_1\ldots L_r=M_{s+1}\Bigg(\sum_{i,j}\mu_{ij}\,L_1\ldots L_iM_{s+2}\ldots M_j\Bigg)\,.$$
This contradicts the hypothesis that $M_{s+1}$ does not divide any $L_i$ (because it has degree $1$).